# Check if there is a Future.delayed or not

Tags: flutter

I want to check if there is any Future.delayed function ongoing. Thanks for any help.

```
    Future.delayed(duration, () async {
      await aFunction();
    });

    bool isAnyDelayedAtTheMoment=?;
```

Comment: Try print something within `Future.delayed`

Comment: Are you trying to tell if there's a pending call to `aFunction()`, or are you trying to tell if there are *any* outstanding callbacks to `Future.delayed` (i.e., in code that you don't control)?  The latter is not possible.

Comment: I try to tell that:

Comment: `print(“future delayed is going”);`

Comment: Within your Future.delayed method, so replace that w `await aFunction();`

Comment: I am editing a text widget with isAnyDelayedAtTheMoment bool

Answer (score 0):

As theiskaa suggested, i did like this:

```
bool isAnyDelayedAtTheMoment=true;

Future.delayed(duration, () async {
      await aFunction();
      isAnyDelayedAtTheMoment=false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as an option you can use `Completed`
full code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final completer = Completer();

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
    await aFunction();
    completer.complete();
  });

  print('isCompleted: ${completer.isCompleted}'); // false

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
    print('isCompleted: ${completer.isCompleted}'); // true
  });

}
```